# Plot time on Y axis

Tags: chart.js

I want to plot the time when the sun sets. Here is my code:

```
var ctxIndex = document.getElementById('sunset');
var myChart = new Chart(ctxIndex, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ['19.09.19', '21.09.19', '22.09.19'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Sunset',
            data: ['20:18', '20:18', '20:15'],
            backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'],
            borderColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

How can I configure chart.js to display the time of '20:18' on the Y axis?

I have seen an example that does this for a bubble chart but I am not able to use that solution in my line chart.

Comment: Can you post a link or the code of the bubble chart example that does what you want? Thanks!

Comment: Okay, i just realized that this question was for angular and not for chart.js. However here the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55058468/display-time-in-y-axis-bubble-chart

Comment: You have to add `type: 'time` to the yAxes-options. You find many other questions and answers for the time-properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55058468/display-time-in-y-axis-bubble-chart) specified in the comments, here is the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-terk6f) with the chart.

A couple of remakrs:

- I found it more convenient to convert `hh:mm` data to minutes

```js
var sunsetHours = ['20:18', '20:18', '20:15'].map(hour => {
  var hourMinutes = hour.split(':');
  var minutes = parseInt(hourMinutes[0]) * 60 + parseInt(hourMinutes[1]);
  return minutes;
});
```

- to achieve something similar to the example from the comments, the code below creates <s>1440</s> 1441 possible labels for the yAxis (for each possible minute). The getHourString() function converts minutes to labels (e.g. `121` becomes `02:01`)

```js
var yLabels = [];
var stepMinutes = 60;
for (var minute = 0; minute <= 1440; minute += 1) {
  yLabels.push(getHourString(minute));
}

/* removed fragment */

function getHourString(minute) {
  var hours = Math.floor(minute / 60);
  var minutes = minute % 60;
  return `${Math.floor(hours / 10) > 0 ? hours : "0" + hours}:${Math.floor(minutes / 10) > 0 ? minutes : "0" + minutes}`;
}
```

- as a bonus I've added also custom [tooltip](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html) so that when you hover on the point it will get `20:18` instead of the `1218`

```js
tooltips: {
  callbacks: {
    label: (tooltipItem, data) => {
      // console.log(tooltipItem);
      return yLabels[tooltipItem.yLabel];
    }
  }
}
```

- I've noticed also that only the first point is red, so I've changed this

```js
backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'],
borderColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'],
```

to this

```js
backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works like a charm :-)
Also very kind of you fixing the problem that only the first point is red.
Since I am using Laravel and formatting the data anyway before sending it to the view as '20:18', '20:15' I am thinking about doing that first calculation from you already in PHP so I just need to plot the data.

Answer (score 0):

The trickiest part is the date parsing and formatting. But if you do it right, it is very powerful.

You find the full example in my [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/vesocapezi/4/edit?html,js,output).

```
let sData = {}
sData.label = ['19.09.19', '21.09.19', '22.09.19']
sData.time = ['20:18', '20:18', '20:15']

let chartData = {}
chartData.label = parseDate(sData.label)
chartData.time = parseTime(sData.time)

function parseDate(dates){
  let parsedDates = []
  for (let x = 0; x < dates.length; x++) {
    parsedDates.push(moment(dates[x], "DD.MM.YYYY").format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
  }
  return parsedDates
}

function parseTime(times){
  let parsedTime = []
  for (let x = 0; x < times.length; x++) {
    let words = times[x].split(':')
    parsedTime.push(parseInt(words[0])*60 + parseInt(words[1]))   
  }
  return parsedTime
}

let ctx = document.getElementById('chart');

let time_data = {
  labels: chartData.label,
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Sunset',
    data: chartData.time,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
    borderWidth: 1
  }]
};

let time_options = {
  responsive: true,
  title: {
    display: true,
    text: 'Sunset'
  },
  legend: {
    display: false
  },
  tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
      label: function(tooltipItem, data){
        let value = parseInt(tooltipItem.value)
        if (value%60 < 10)
          return Math.floor(value/60) + ":" + 0 + value%60
        else
          return Math.floor(value/60) + ":" + value%60
      },
      title: function(tooltipItem, data){
        let label = tooltipItem[0].label
        console.log(label)
        console.log(moment(label).format('DD.MM.YYYY'))
        return moment(label).format('DD.MM.YYYY')
      }
    },
    displayColors: false
  },
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      type: 'time',
      time: {
        minUnit: 'day',
        unitStepSize: 1,
        displayFormats: {
          day: 'DD.MM.' 
        }
      }
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        //min: 0,
        //max: 1440,
        precision: 0,
        callback: function(value, index, values) {
          if (value%60 < 10)
            return Math.floor(value/60) + ":" + 0 + value%60
          else 
            return Math.floor(value/60) + ":" + value%60
        }
      }      
    }]
  }
};

let chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "line",
  data: time_data,
  options: time_options
});
```

Comment: @cYnd Btw do you want the xAxis to have a time scale (I'm not sure because you didn't write anything about that in your question and your code)? That's what my code is focussing. If not then kasptom's answer is easier and shorter.

Comment: The time scale is optional but still nice to have. Since I can only mark one comment as answer I'll go with kasptom's because it's easier and shorter ;-)